# Convert timestamp to datetime.time python

Tags: python, timestamp, python-datetime

I am working on a dataset which contains the time between various operations in python. The original format of time data is hh:mm. When I read the data in python from excel, it is showing timestamp. for example, the time in excel sheet is 82:35 but python is reading as 1900-01-03 10:35:00. So I want the original values that is time format.

```
datetime.time(82, 35)
Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:10:00')
```

I tried to convert into datetime but it shows error.

Comment: Hi,

Good question but please add some more information about the error it shows and even better would be to also use Pastebin to share some more code cause now it can be many errors you are getting.

Also add the packages u use as maybe you will be importing python modules or libraries that you use to convert the dates/timestamps etc...

Also add some things your tried already like you will probabbly already have checked that the database table type is correct as timestamp if you store it in a db, how do you read from the file? Do u use UTF-8 or what encoding is used?

Extra info plz.

Comment: what is the time format you need. In hours,minutes,seconds?

Comment: Read about [timedelta-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: Thank you. Dear vishnu, the time format I need is like 82:35 hrs